# Is it necessary to add non-retina images for latest iOS Apps

Tags: ios, iphone

It seems like Apple is now manufacturing iOS devices with retina display only. We usually keep two versions of images like `IconCricket@2x.png / IconCricket.png`. So I would assume now we can only add `@2x.png` into App. Is that okay? or Is it still necessary to add 1x images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add only @2x images thats enough...
   But for your help in Xcode-5 there are very easy way to add images for your project ..
   go to project and add images accordingly .....

1- App Icon
  2- Launch Images

Comment: What you mean is "Use Asset Catalog" - that's indeed nice to use. If you use it, pay attention to set the ''iOS icon is pre-rendered'' option to true if you don't want the glare effect on iOS 6 devices - this setting is not taken over from your old project settings. You can find it in the Attribute Inspector of the AppIcon catalog.

Answer (score 1):

It's not. You may use Retina images only. They will be downscaled on non-Retina devices